# Comparing Arrays LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can I compare to array in linq and get all elements where there is at least one intersection?
Example:

```
selectes = {1,5,7} 
Bands[0].SongsID {1,9} 
Bands[1].SongsID {5,6}
Bands[2].SongsID {4,6}
```

I need to select `Bands[0]` and `Bands[1]`.
I tried this:

```
var selectes2 = Bands.Where(t => t.SongsID.Intersect(selectes));
```

Bands class:

```
public class Band
{
    public int ID                { get; set; }
    public string Name           { get; set; }
    public DateTime YearOfCreate { get; set; }
    public string Country        { get; set; }
    public int[] SongsID         { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please change your example to compilable C# code (e.g. what is the type of `SongsID`?). Consider: What is the return type of `Intersect`? What type does `Where` expect the delegate to return? What method will do the conversion?

Comment: So you want to select any band that has any songID in your selectes list?

Comment: @NetMage im add Band class

Comment: @JonathonChase
Yes, any band that has SongsID[] in selectes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var selectes2 = Bands.Where(t => t.SongsID.Intersect(selectes).Any());
```

Comment: Time complexity is O(N^2), performance would be an issue here

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I know that) Of course we can easy get guaranteed complexity O(N log N) if use SortedSet or even O(N) in average if use HashSet. But I think, author of this question was searching for the easiest and shortest solution)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to select any band that has any song ID that matches your list of ids, you could accomplish that with this:

```
var matchingBands = Bands.Where(band => band.SongsID.Any(selectes.Contains));
```

Comment: Array Contains has time complexity of O(N), same solution would work better by converting `int[]` to `Hashset<int>`. This would bring down solution time complexity to O(N) instead of O(N^2)